# Using hyphens opposed to underscores with in page URLs

Tags: seo, pages

Someone told me the other day that Google likes url's with hyphens (e.g. a-page-title) opposed to url's with underscores (e.g. a_page_title).

Assuming this is correct is there a way to make Expression Engine use hyphens in it's page url's opposed to the underscores it uses by default?

Comment: It would seem that dashes have now been made the default (on version 2.7.1 here).

Answer (score 4):

Admin > Channel Administration > Global Preferences > Word Separator for URL Titles > Dash

Or, in your config.php file (or your bootstrap equivalent):

```
$config['word_separator'] = 'dash';
```

Comment: thanks ... this does not seem to be working for me when I make the change through the CP. Are there any other steps I need to perform through the CP or on my files?

Comment: It only works for new entries. Existing entries will need to be updated manually.